# Convert generic type object to own type

Tags: c#, generics, mef

I have an abstract class `MySerializer<T>` which is the base for other ones such as `XMLSerializer<T>` and it is managed by MEF.

When I instantiate serializing object i want to have e.g. `XMLSerializer<Object>` but then I would like to convert it to `XMLSerializer<MyClass>`. Is it possible?

Comment: I don't think it's possible. `XMLSerializer<Object>` and `XMLSerializer<MyClass>` are two _completely_ different types. There is no built-in cast. Since these classes are yours, you may implement a custom (not-identity-preserving) _conversion_, but I guess that's not what you want (it sounds you're rather looking for some kind of _cast_ instead of _conversion_)..

Comment: @Rene It is just because I want to use `DataContractSerializer`. With known type e. g. `MyClass` it works, but when I pass `Object` it throws an exception to use `DataContractResolver`.

Comment: @Piotr196 - Each type that is serialized requires its own specially constructed `DataContractSerializer`; that's why the [constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404901(v=vs.110).aspx) takes a `Type` argument.  It's not like Json.NET or `JavaScriptSerializer` where one serializer can serialize any type.

Comment: @dbc thank you, I ommited the problem in not a clear way checking if `T is MyClass` and instantiating `DataContractSerializer` with `MyClass`

Comment: Then do you still need an answer?  If so could you [edit] your question to share a [mcve] showing what code problem you are having?  See also [ask].

Comment: No, thank you. I solved it in a specific way but it works.